# cannot capture packets on wireshark without internet

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, windows-8.1, wireshark, packet

I am using Wireshark on my Windows 8.1 Pro 32-bit pa and whenever I start Wireshark without internet, it can't capture ant packets. But when I am connected to the internet, it captures packets
form all networks around me. So do I need internet to capture packets?

Comment: This is a long shot, but if you have Wireshark set to do name resolution, turn it off (in capture options). Maybe Wireshark is choking because it can't resolve any names when you don't have a connection to any DNS servers.

Comment: which option? There are 4 different ones.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark does not allow to capture WiFi packets under Windows. Install Acrylic WiFi software to enable wireshark wifi compatibility.

[Wireshark WiFi under windows](https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/blog/how-to-capture-wifi-traffic-using-wireshark-on-windows/)